# Neyman-Pearson Testing: Swapping the main and alternative hypotheses to ensure P(Type I) < P(Type II)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, decision-theory, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have been reading up on hypothesis testing, and realized I misunderstood something, which made me mix Fisher's p-values with Neyman-Pearson's critical regions. I am going to amend that situation, so I have been reading up. The importance of one thing is very clear to me, but I can't seem to find an example of how to implement it, so I ask for your help.

Let's say I work on a well-controlled production process that produces parts with some measurable quality aspect $Q = \mu_r$, normally distributed with standard deviation $\sigma_r$. I am investigating a change that I suspect increases $Q = \mu_t > \mu_r$, without changing standard deviation. I can easily estimate a minimum effect size $\delta$ based on an economic argument. I would plan a one-sample t-test. I have just learned to replace my old null hypothesis with a main hypothesis $H_M$ and explicitly add the minimum effect size in the statement, so we have:
$$
H_M:\mu_t-\mu_r \le 0 \pm \delta \\
H_t:\mu_t-\mu_r > 0 + \delta
$$

This looks similar to my old null hypothesis, and I select $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and calculate the required sample size $n$. But this brings me to something I never quite understood, but I think I am on the right track now. Below I ask for a little push in the right direction.

There are (a lot of) cases in my daily work where the opportunity cost of failing to detect a real improvement outweighs the cost of the work I waste pursuing a path dictated by a falsely rejected $H_M$. This prompts me to set $\beta < \alpha$, which I'm not supposed to do. That always confused me. However, I read that Neyman-Pearson suggest a simple solution: I have to swap my hypotheses (which is main, and which is the alternative). It actually makes perfect sense, except that I am not quite clear on how I would do that. What would the hypotheses look like, and how would I perform the test?

I am very much "spoiled" by my previous training, I have to un-learn some of it and then re-learn those bits. So I might be overthinking this. Is it a matter of simply swapping the inequality signs, and taking the other tail of the t-test? If so, why is it not a problem that $\mu_t$ might be larger than $\delta$, whereas we treat $\mu_r$ as "known"?